# How can i return if inside def

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 enter = ('255.255.0.0')
        def ff (s):
        s = s.split('.')
        B1 = str(bin(int(s[0])))
        B2 = str(bin(int(s[1])))
        B3 = str(bin(int(s[2])))
        B4 = str(bin(int(s[3])))
        s = B1[2:],B2[2:],B3[2:],B4[2:]
           for i in s:
              if len(i) < 8:
                i = 8 - len(i)
                r =i * '0'


    return s


    print(ff(enter))
```

what is wrong in above code? i need the output should be like the [11111111,11111111,00000000,0000000]

Comment: Please fix your indentation before others can help you.

Comment: For one thing, the indentation in your code is off, which is critical in Python. That may be causing your problems, so check and correct it. For another, what incorrect result are you getting now? Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were close. The problem was that you were not updating your `s` for the `0` values when `len(j) < 8`.

The fix is that you convert your tuple `s` to a list and then update the values for `0` as follows. I have commented the modified lines.

```
enter = ('255.255.0.0')

def ff (s):
    s = s.split('.')
    B1 = str(bin(int(s[0])))
    B2 = str(bin(int(s[1])))
    B3 = str(bin(int(s[2])))
    B4 = str(bin(int(s[3])))
    s = B1[2:],B2[2:],B3[2:],B4[2:]
    s = list(s) # Convert tuple to list

    for i, j in enumerate(s): # Enumerate to access index for modifying
        if len(j) < 8:
            j = 8 - len(j)
            s[i] = j * '0'

    return s

print(ff(enter))

# ['11111111', '11111111', '0000000', '0000000']
```

Comment: Why the downvote for no reason? Can the voter explain rather than random downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Bazingaa pointed out the problem of your code and offered a fix. Here is another way to fix your problem:

```
def ff (s):
    s = s.split('.')
    s = [bin(int(x)) for x in s]  # ['0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b0', '0b0']
    s = [x[2:] for x in s]        # ['11111111', '11111111', '0', '0']
    s = [x.zfill(8) for x in s]   # ['11111111', '11111111', '00000000', '00000000']
    return s
```

Or we can combine those lines together:

```
def ip_to_binary(ip):
    return [bin(int(x))[2:].zfill(8) for x in ip.split('.')]
```

**Notes**

- The key here is to use the `zfill` method, which is part of a string object
- The function `bin` returns a string, so we don't need to call `str` to convert it to string again
- Please avoid using cryptic names such as `ff`, `s`, ... They makes the code harder to understand
- Avoid using parentheses unnecessarily: `enter = ('255.255.0.0')` is the same as `enter = '255.255.0.0'`